# Android relative layout aligning components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi I am having problem with android relative layout design. I just cant get it to put 4 buttons around one centered button. See XML below as an example. Controls are pretty much self explanatory.

Thank you all for help.

#### Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_test_wholeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_test_relativeLayoutMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/main_panel_a"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/center"
        android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/center"
        android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use gravity of the relativelayout
Instead use this for center ImageButton

```
android:centerInParent = "true"
```

I hope it will work

Comment: It works for central button but if i put top button to be above central button it doesn't move. <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/center"
            android:src="@drawable/more_baby_call" />

Answer (score 0):

try setting this:

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"